# Initialize Array of Pointers by Reference C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, reference

Basically what I am trying to do is initialize my array within a function, but it segfaults:

```
void func(int **a, int x, int y) {
    a = new int*[x];

    for (int i=0; i<x; i++)
        a[i] = new int[y];
}

void main() {
    int **a;    
    func(a, 2, 3);
}
```

However if I init the array outside the function then pass it, everything works perfectly, i can assign values to it / print them. What I'm struggling with is passing the reference of my array so I don't have to init it outside the function.

```
void func(int **a, int x, int y) {  
    for (int i=0; i<x; i++)
        a[i] = new int[y];
}

void main() {
    int x = 2;
    int **a = new int*[x];  
    func(a, x, 3);
}
```

Comment: I don't believe that code seg-faults.  However, do be aware that the `a` in `main` is not being modified.

Comment: I lose interest the second I see `int**a` in supposedly c++ code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's biting you here is C's (and C++'s) lack of by-reference argument passing. The `a` in `main()` is distinct from the `a` in `func()`:

1. `a` is declared in `main`.
2. `a` is passed by value (because there's no other way) to `func`.
3. The `a` in `func` is assigned to.
4. `func` returns. Its `a` is destroyed (leaking memory), and `main`'s `a` is left uninitialised.
5. ???
6. `main` tries to use `a`. ***Segfault!***

There are a few possible solutions here:

1. Do it the classic C way: pass a pointer to the value. In this case, the parameter will be `int ***a`, which is gettng a little ridiculous, but whatever.

   ```
   void func(int ***a, int x, int y) {  
       *a = new int*[x];
       for (int i=0; i<x; i++)
           (*a)[i] = new int[y];
   }

   int main(int argc, char **argv) {
       ...
       int **a;
       func(&a, 2, 3);
       ...
   }
   ```
2. Do it the C++ way: pass a reference.

   ```
   void func(int **&a, int x, int y) {
       //          ^
       // This is the only change. Neat!
   ```
3. Do it the proper (in my opinion) way: return a value from the function, and initialise the array from that.

   ```
   int **func(int x, int y) {
       int **a = new int*[x]; // EDIT: Fixed stupid typo bug
       // existing code
       return a;
   }

   int main(int argc, char **argv) {
       ...
       int **a = func(2, 3);
       ...
   }
   ```

Comment: The second way was what i was looking for, now it works flawlessly. Thanks for comparing the 3 different ways.

Answer (score 1):

What your original code does is modify the local variable in func, not the local variable in main.
This will do what you want:

```
void func(int **&a, int x, int y) {
    a = new int*[x];

    for (int i=0; i<x; i++)
            a[i] = new int[y];
}

void main() {
    int **a;    
    func(a, 2, 3);
}
```

Otherwise I can't see why you'd be getting a seg fault, unless you are trying to access the array in main after calling func.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example. the call to `func` does not change the value of `a` in `main`. You can have `func` return a pointer to the array it creates and then assign that pointer to the variable in `main.`
Changing your sample code would look like this:

```
int** func(int x, int y) {
   int **a = new int*[x];

   for (int i=0; i<x; i++)
      a[i] = new int[y];

   return a;

}

void main() {
   int **a;    
   a = func( 2, 3);
}
```